# Convert a 'https://' request to 'http://' with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting 404 for https request as I am modifying an existing project which was using https. I don't have ssl and I don't need the https too. I changed all the base_url and links to normal http.For converting all the https to http I changed my .htaccess to this-

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

### Url rewrite ###

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=5

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(static|auth|register|secure|js|css|img)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

#Other redirects
RewriteRule \.json$ notfound.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^viz/apps/.+\.js$ notfound.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^viz/index.php - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^viz/(.*)$ viz/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 notfound

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

But it is not working. What should I do to convert all https requests for image,css,js to normal http request. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

The Previous .htaccess which was targeted for https was like this-

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

### Url rewrite ###

RewriteOptions inherit
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=5

#Everything to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/insecure/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/viz/insecure/.*
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/viz/index.php/insecure/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Other redirects
RewriteRule \.json$ notfound.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^viz/apps/.+\.js$ notfound.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^viz/index.php - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^viz/(.*)$ viz/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 notfound
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you don't suppot HTTPS, how do you expect a client to connect to you and get a response from your server in the first place?

Comment: That is matter of the server side. You, client side, can not change the server.

Comment: I am modifying an existing project. It was created for https. But now I don't need it. So I cleared all base_url and links to normal http. Still it is going for https. I changed the .htaccess but no help.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is not capable of establishing a connection over https, it is not possible to redirect the client when they request a page over https. It's the server that needs to send this header, but since no connection is established, it can't send a header either.

Even if your server were capable of serving https, adding a https-to-http-rule would not solve your problem. You would end up redirecting https to http via Apache, and redirecting from http to https via your application. You will need to fix your application to solve this problem.